# After calling add method from vuex second argument doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I create vuex with addNews method Inside of it and pass two arguments, title and body of item. But after calling that method inside my component it only prints my first argument title in HTML. Also i try to console.log body and i get data
This is my method in vuex

```
  async addNews({ commit }, title, body) {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`,
      { title: title, body: body }
    );
    commit("addNews", response.data);
  },
```

And here is component where I call it

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn class="mb-5" fab dark color="primary" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
          <v-icon dark> mdi-plus </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>

      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="text-h5 blue lighten-2">
          ADD NEW POST
        </v-card-title>

        <v-text-field v-model="title" required></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field v-model="body" required></v-text-field>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="primary"
            class="mr-4"
            @click="
              onSubmit();
              dialog = false;
            "
          >
            Do It
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "AddNews",
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      body: "",
      dialog: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addNews"]),
    onSubmit() {
      this.addNews(this.title, this.body);
      this.title = "";
      this.body = "";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: `dispatch` allows to provide only one argument (the payload) to an action. In case there should be several, it should be an object

Answer (score 2):

Try passing an object with arguments to your action:

```
 async addNews({ commit }, { title, body }) {
   const response = await axios.post(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`,
    { title, body }
  );
 commit("addNews", response.data);
},
```